# Как изменить границы спрайта

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить границу спрайта(колайдера), чтобы эта яма была активна?

Comment: Вместо Box Collider 2d использовать Polygon collider 2d? Или составить эту форму из нескольких Box Collider 2d

Comment: `EdgeCollider`.